# Create page with specific template using plugin

Tags: wordpress

i am creating wordpress plugin for my own contact us page. in that i am creating one contact us page when plugin activated.

**my code is**

```
 function createPage()
{
 global $user_ID;
 $page['post_type']    = 'page';
 $page['post_content'] = 'hello this page created by plugin';
 $page['post_parent']  = 0;
 $page['post_author']  = $user_ID;
 $page['post_status']  = 'publish';
 $page['post_title']   = 'Dynamic page';
 //    $page = apply_filters('yourplugin_add_new_page', $page, 'teams');
 $pageid = wp_insert_post ($page);
 }
```

and it's working fine. it's creating new page also. now my question is i want to assign specific template to this page. i don't know how to do it..

can you please suggest me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is you plugin also creating the template inside the theme folder? Suggestion: make sure the page doesn't exist before creating it, if we disable/enable the plugin you'll have duplicates, no?

Comment: yes template file is exist in my plugin dir... yes you are right.. i am deleting page when we are deactivate plugin..

Comment: @b__ is there any function which is used to insert data in to table wp_postmeta? like here for wp_post i am using wp_insert_post()

Comment: yep, `update_post_meta`, check the docs, all the info you need is there ;)

Comment: @b__ in the postmeta table i am finding any data related to my page... i have to insert all meta keys manually or does wordpress do it automatically in my case?

Comment: @b__ if you don't mind then let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40244/discussion-between-404-not-found-and-bindiya-patoliya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename of a Page's assigned custom template is stored as the value of a Custom Field named '_wp_page_template' (in the wp_postmeta database table).So you can set that page meta to that particular template name.

Comment: ohh great i found it... let's try to do it... thanks for direction and one question how retrieve page id ?

Comment: You have use `wp_insert_post()` function to create page .Right?

Comment: yes i have used it... to insert into postmeta any function is there?

Comment: <?php add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique); ?>

Comment: You get the page id like this `$pageid = wp_insert_post ($page);`

Comment: it's not inserting any data in wp_postmeta... manually i have to install these all metakey ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40244/discussion-between-404-not-found-and-bindiya-patoliya)